# INSERT suspended in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

An "Add New" form is sporadically crashing after a long timeout. The form collects a lot of data, and when it is saved, it does a fair bit of processing and then and then inserts many records.

We can reproduce this fairly easily on our test instance but haven't been able to figure out why. Finally with Stackify Prefix (a very nice free tool), we caught the system twice blocking on a simple, one-record INSERT, the same one each time. It sits in "suspended" status for 300 seconds and then the transaction is aborted.

The query in question is below, first as extracted from SQL Server using a "Show me what is running" query, and the second from Stackify Prefix. I'm not sure how to get the data values without installing a build with debug mode turned on, but I'm hesitant to update the build on the test instance in case that disturbs whatever is helping us to at least reproduce the bug sometimes.

I'm looking for any suggestions on how to debug this further. The query's execution plan is simple, it only has one index (on the primary key), no triggers or constraints. This issue has happened on multiple instances so I don't suspect database corruption. Basically I would like to know if there is a way to find out what is causing this query to sit in "suspended" state for 300 seconds. Thank you.

```
(@0 int,@1 decimal(10,3),@2 datetime2(7),@3 int,@4 int)
INSERT [dbo].[Deliveries]([OrderId], [DeliveredQuantity], [DeliveryDate], [Notes], [Status], [ReturnedQuantity], [ReturnedDate], [ReturnedReason], [ReceivedQuantity], [ReceivedDate], [ReceivedByUserId], [ApprovedByUserId], [ApprovedDate], [DeliveredId], [IsDeleted])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, @3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @4, NULL)
    SELECT [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Deliveries]
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

INSERT [dbo].[Deliveries]
           ([OrderId],[DeliveredQuantity],[DeliveryDate],[Notes],[Status],[ReturnedQuantity],[ReturnedDate],[ReturnedReason],[ReceivedQuantity],[ReceivedDate],[ReceivedByUserId],[ApprovedByUserId],[ApprovedDate],[DeliveredId],[IsDeleted])
VALUES (1250 /* @0 */,'Unsupported Type' /* @1 */,'Error parsing date' /* @2 */,NULL,2 /* @3 */,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,26859 /* @4 */,NULL)
```

Comment: Try with this query to find out why your session is waiting for  

`SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=##
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id=##
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where session_id = ##` Replace ## with your session where your INSERT being run

Comment: And, It's better get the Identity value in a Variable and use it `DECLARE @Id INT

INSERT........

SET @Id = @@IDENTITY`

Comment: @SQLServerBuddy: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Yes! I agree with you on this

Comment: @SQLServerBuddy I was able to reproduce the issue again and ran your 3 SELECTS with the request session ID, and all 3 records returned data. So this will help us debug further. I believe you have answered the question I was asking for which was to provide the next step. Can you provide it as an answer so I can select it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below DMVs help you to investigate further

```
SELECT Start_Time [Request Started], [Status],blocking_session_id [Blocked by], wait_type [Process Waiting for],
wait_resource [Waiting on]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=## 

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id=## 

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where session_id = ##
```

Replace **##** with your session where your INSERT being run